# The SQL statement keeps giving me click through rate of 0

Tags: sql

So the question is from datalemur:
https://datalemur.com/questions/click-through-rate

I noticed that if i phrase my 14th line as this (brackets around the division) :

```
SELECT cta.app_id, ROUND(100.0 * (cta.click_count/ ita.impression_count),2) AS ctr
```

then I get 0
But if I remove brackets then I get the correct values 66.7 and 33.33

```
SELECT cta.app_id, ROUND(100.0 * cta.click_count/ ita.impression_count,2) AS ctr
```

I don't understand the reason for this discrepancy.

This is my entire query:

```
WITH click_table AS (SELECT app_id, COUNT(event_type) AS click_count 
FROM events 
    WHERE event_type = 'click'
    AND EXTRACT(year FROM timestamp) = '2022'
GROUP BY events.app_id),

impression_table AS (SELECT app_id, COUNT(event_type) AS impression_count 
FROM events 
    WHERE event_type ='impression'
    AND EXTRACT(year FROM timestamp) = '2022'
GROUP BY events.app_id)
    
SELECT cta.app_id, ROUND(100.0 * cta.click_count/ ita.impression_count,2) AS ctr

FROM click_table AS cta
LEFT JOIN 
impression_table AS ita ON 
  cta.app_id = ita.app_id;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Classic integer division issue, you need to convert to decimal first. Side notes: `COUNT(event_type)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` unless `event_type` has nulls. The two CTEs can be combined into one without any joins, by using conditional aggregation such as `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 'click')` or `COUNT(CASE WHEN event_type = 'click' THEN 1 END)`. Don't use `EXTRACT` in `WHERE` and `ON` conditions, as it prevents use of indexes, instead use date ranges `timestamp >= DATE '2022-01-01' AND timestamp < DATE '2023-01-01'`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and the extra side notes, much appreciated!
Okay definitely agree for using timestamp ranges, from my understanding EXTRACT would evaluate each row individually and thus is more computationally innefficient.